# Data being edited in .opvn config when vpn app http gets .opvn files from my host. Adds my wordpress site code and removes the config

Tags: wordpress, web-development, cpanel, http

I have a VPN app that pulls `.ovpn` files from a folder on my website : `/home/mywebsitename/public_html/remoteovpn`. When I add the `.opvn` files to this folder and my app pulls them from https request, you can go to the files in the browser link, you can see them and read all the config no problem even dl them. But when my app pulls the files it gets the filenames and makes the `.opvn` files, but edits the files with my website WP theme data, not the `.ovpn` config data. I can't figure why it is doing this. Any help would be appreciated been trying for 2 days.

VPS with CentOS 7 and cPanel with Wordpress theme.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "edits the files with my website wp theme data, not the .ovpn config data"  Also, are you aware that OVPN files have a private key in them and its not a great idea for them to be publicly accessible?

Comment: I wonder if the issue relates to the mime type associated with the .ovpn file ?  I don't think we can be of more assistance unless we know the app that pulls the files and how the server and if/how mime.types are set.

Comment: Man, I thought you had it. There was no mime for ovpn files so I added, but no change the files are still edited. But I noticed in the wp-admin file mgr the folder and files have a little padlock on them. no other files have this that I can see. And i can't find how to unlock the files.